# String replacement in sed

Tags: sed

How to replace BINARY(any integer of 64 bit) with BYTEA:

Example1:

```
Input:
BINARY(28)

Output:
BYTEA
```

Example2:

```
Input:
BINARY(234)

Output:
BYTEA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/BINARY([0-9]\{1,3\})/BYTEA/g'
```

where `s` is replace `[0-9]\{1,3\}` is a series of one to three digits and the `g` at the end for changing all entries in a line. So just adapt the number of digits accordingly.